How to dynamically reset and clear the control form inside the Group box?
I have a GroupBox in the mainForm which is Form1.cs I am rendering an userControl form in the group box by adding the form. See the code below for reference.
M_sampleUCForm.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
M_sampleUCForm.Size = testProgramGroupBox.ClientSize;
testProgramGroupBox.Controls.Add(M_sampleUCForm);
M_sampleUCForm.LoadTestProgramForm(sampleData.ToArray());

Here sampleData has three data namely "A, B, C". So, by executing the LoadTestProgrmForm function I am rendering three Labels with text as A, B, C. See below the code for userControlForm.
    public partial class testProgramForm : UserControl
    {
        private Dictionary<string, Label> testLabels = new Dictionary<string, Label>();
        private int labelTop = 10;
        private int labelLeft = 20;

        public testProgramForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void LoadTestProgramForm(string[] testProg)
        {
            testLabels.Clear();
            foreach (string test in testProg)
            {
                Label testLabel = new Label();
                Label statusLabel = new Label();

                this.Controls.Add(testLabel);
                this.Controls.Add(statusLabel);

                testLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption;
                testLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                testLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(labelLeft, labelTop);
                testLabel.Name = "Label";
                testLabel.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
                testLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 35);
                testLabel.TabIndex = 0;
                testLabel.Text = test;
                testLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

                statusLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLight;
                statusLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                statusLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(labelLeft + 140, labelTop);
                statusLabel.Name = "StatusLabel";
                statusLabel.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
                statusLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 35);
                statusLabel.TabIndex = 1;
                statusLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

                testLabels.Add(test, statusLabel);
                labelTop += 40;
            }
        }
    }

I have a Finish button in the mainForm (Form1.cs), when the button is clicked I want the userControlForm to be reseted. Right now, I am able to clear the groupbox using the line testProgramGroupBox.Controls.Clear() but this only clears the controlForm. Upon rendering the controlForm again, I could see total of 6 labels like A, B, C, A, B, C.
How do I dynamically reset this and adjust the rendering of the label?
Thanks in Advance!
